# Overloaded function failing giving Compiler recursion error

Tags: recursion, clojure

With the following code, I get `#<CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)>` despite the fact that all recurs are in tail positions. If I remove the recur from the one-argument version, it stops complaining. Why is this happening?

```
(defn remove-duplicates "Removes duplicate elements of lst. 

For example, given (1 2 3 1 4 1 2), remove-duplicates returns a sequence 
containing the elements (1 2 3 4), in some order."
  [lst] (recur (rest lst) (set (first lst)))
  [lst uniques] (cond (zero? (count lst)) uniques
                      :else (cond
                              (some (partial = (first lst)) uniques)
                              (recur (rest lst) uniques)
                              :else 
                              (recur (rest lst) (first lst)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't split up the multi-arity bodies right. Should read `(defn foo ([x] (...)) ([x y] (...)))`. This causes the compiler to think you're doing totally different stuff, which probably accounts for your issue.

Comment: Oh, bah.  Forgot the needed parens around those. Thanks;

Comment: @havvy Also, you can't `recur` across arities. Only inside one arity. You have to call your function directly with the different arity.

Comment: @kotarak if you'd make it an answer I'd give you +1 -- removing those 2 bugs nearly solve Havvy's issue (one more bug, see my ans below)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you know that all you want is `(def remove-duplicates set)` or -- if you want a vector -- `(def remove-duplicates-vec (comp vec set))`, right?

Five things here:

1. As amalloy noticed, you should've added parens
2. As kotarak noticed, you can't recur between arities
3. You can't call `(set (first lst))` because `set` wants coll. If you want, do something like `(set (vector (first [1 2 3 2 3])))` but this is neither pretty nor idiomatic
4. Doing `(cond pred1 code1 :else (cond pred2a code2a :else code2b))` could be made simplier: `(cond pred1 code1 pred2a code2a :else code2b)` -- what you did is treated [`cond` macro](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/cond) as if it were `if` (which is a built-in as far as I know)
5. Your last tail-call is also wrong. Assume we've started with `[1 2 3 2 1]`

   1. When you call it first you have following arguments: `([2 3 2 1] #{1})` (I've skipped the boring part)
   2. Then you have last predicate true, so you go with `([3 2 1] 2)` and this is obviously wrong because you wanted `([3 2 1] #{1 2})`. You probably want to call `(recur (rest lst) (conj uniques (first lst)))`

Summing up:

```
(defn remove-duplicates
  ([lst] (remove-duplicates (rest lst) #{(first coll)}))
  ([lst uniques]
    (cond
      (zero? (count lst)) uniques
      (some (partial = (first lst)) uniques)
      (recur (rest lst) uniques)
      :else 
      (recur (rest lst) (conj uniques (first lst))))))
```

Comment: `(set (vector (first coll)))` is silly. There are so many nicer ways to write that: `(set [(first coll)])`, `(hash-set (first coll))`, `#{(first coll)}`...ordered from worst to best, IMO.